# Como recorrer un array dentro de un objeto y extraer su valor para formar un nuevo objeto con cada valor recorrido?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Tengo este array de objetos.

```
Obj = [{fruta: 'frutilla, limon, naranja', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'},
      {fruta: 'frutilla, pera, banana', verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}]
```

Dentro de fruta tengo un string que necesito separar en un solo valor y que quede algo asi

```
Obj = [{fruta: 'frutilla', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'}, 
   {fruta: 'limon', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'},
   {fruta: 'naranja', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'},
   {fruta: 'frutilla, verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}
   {fruta: 'pera', verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}``
   {fruta: 'banana', verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}
  ]
```

Tendria que repetir el objeto cambiando la propiedad fruta.
Probe muuuuchas cosas, mis ultimos intentos se veian asi

```
const nuevoObj = obj.map((item, indice) => ({...item, cantidad: item.fruta[indice]}))
```

Pero me da undefined, no logro encontrar la solución. Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Obj = [{fruta: 'frutilla, limon, naranja', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'},
      {fruta: 'frutilla, pera, banana', verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}]

    let arrayFinal = Obj.map(a=>{
    //Separar string por sus comas (,)
    temporal = a.fruta.split(",")
      //Recorrer el arreglo
      return temporal.map(b=>{return {fruta:b.trim(),verdura:a.verdura,caja:a.caja}})
    }).flat()

/* resultado: 
[
  {fruta: 'frutilla',verdura: 'Lechuga',caja: 'Grande'},
  {fruta: 'limon',verdura: 'Lechuga',caja: 'Grande'},
  {fruta: 'naranja',verdura: 'Lechuga',caja: 'Grande'},
  {fruta: 'frutilla',verdura: 'Mandioca',caja: 'Media'},
  {fruta: 'pera',verdura: 'Mandioca',caja: 'Media'},
  {fruta: 'banana',verdura: 'Mandioca',caja: 'Media'}
]

*/
```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, yo lo haría así espero que te sirva

Comment: Tambien funciono perfecto! voy a usar esta respuesta ya que deja todo en un mismo array de objetos. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias por usar mi respuesta, recuerda que puedes aceptar mi respuesta como la indicada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), que recibe dos parámetros.

1. Función callback (devolución de llamada), que recibe dos parámetros obligatorios; para este caso, no se necesitan los opcionales:

   - acumulador: En esta variable se van a estar aplicando todos los cambios y, al final del ciclo, es la que será devuelta como resultado
   - elemento: `reduce()` recorre el arreglo y esta variable es el elemento actual de cada iteración
2. acumulador: Aquí se establece el valor inicial del acumulador y puede ser de cualquier tipo, no necesariamente un arreglo

```js
let obj = [
    {fruta: 'frutilla, limon, naranja', verdura: 'Lechuga', caja: 'Grande'},
    {fruta: 'frutilla, pera, banana', verdura: 'Mandioca', caja: 'Media'}
];

// La función callback del método reduce recibe dos argumentos:
// acc - Acumulador
// cur - Elemento en cada iteración
let combined = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Separar las frutas en un arreglo, por coma y espacio
    let fruits = cur.fruta.split(', ');
    // Recorrer cada fruta e insertar en acumulador,
    // manteniendo las propiedades verdura y caja del elemento actual
    fruits.forEach(fruit => acc.push({
        fruta: fruit,
        verdura: cur.verdura,
        caja: cur.caja
    }));
    return acc;
}, []); // Iniciar acumulador con arreglo vacío

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto! muchas gracias!!!